# Fetch record using External ID with specified fields

Tags: rest-api, externalid

I would like to fetch a record over standard REST API via a field marked External ID (like [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_retrieve_with_externalid.htm)), but limit my fetched fields to just my required fields (e.g. using the fields parameter [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_field_values.htm)). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving an object via its external ID using sObject Rows REST resource will bring all fields back, the platform won't let you filter them for a native sObject. You have to use the `query` REST resource

`/services/data/<api version>/query/?q=SELECT+SomeField+from+MyObject+where+MyObject__c+=+'<yourExternalId>'`

Apex REST or parameterized search are possible [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715522/salesforce-rest-api-how-to-avoid-leaking-sensitive-data-in-query-parameter).